# How to create a function that returns a byte array in C++? Arduino project

Tags: c++, arduino

I am currently starting to learn C++ via Arduino programming. I am programming an 8*8 LED Matrix, and currently have a semi-working code that uses a joystick to control a dot on screen. Only problem is: it's nearly 1,000 lines long. It's equivalent to writing a 1,000-page essay only saying "Pig, blanket, market" over and over again until I get to the actual logic involved.

My friend suggested to make it shorter, I could make a function which returns a byte.

How does one do this?

```
#include "LedControl.h"

LedControl lc=LedControl(12,11,10,1);
// Pins: DIN,CLK,CS, # of Display connected

// I put all the points on the matrix into an array.
// Ex. a11 is an array which there is a dot at the point (1,1)
// a23 is an array which holds the point (2,3), etc.
// I don't know how to shorten this with for loops, but I know there is a way.
byte a11[] = {
   0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a12[] = {
   0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a13[] = {
   0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a14[] = {
   0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a15[] = {
   0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a16[] = {
   0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a17[] = {
   0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a18[] = {
   0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a21[] = {
   0x00,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a22[] = {
   0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a23[] = {
   0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a24[] = {
   0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a25[] = {
   0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a26[] = {
   0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a27[] = {
   0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a28[] = {
   0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a31[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a32[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a33[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a34[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a35[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a36[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a37[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a38[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a41[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a42[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a43[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a44[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a45[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a46[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a47[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a48[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a51[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a52[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a53[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a54[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a55[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a56[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a57[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a58[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a61[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a62[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a63[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a64[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a65[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a66[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a67[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a68[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,0x00,
};
byte a71[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,0x00,
};
byte a72[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,0x00,
};
byte a73[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,0x00,
};
byte a74[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,0x00,
};
byte a75[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,
};
byte a76[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,0x00,
};
byte a77[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,0x00,
};
byte a78[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,0x00,
};
byte a81[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x80,
};
byte a82[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x40,
};
byte a83[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x20,
};
byte a84[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x10,
};
byte a85[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,
};
byte a86[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x04,
};
byte a87[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x02,
};
byte a88[] = {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x01,
};
byte none[] = //array where no points are lit {
   0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,
};
byte all[] = //array which all points are lit {
   0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,
};
int xPin = A1; //Pins for Joystick and starting int's
int yPin = A0;
int buttonPin = 2;
int xPosition = 0;
int yPosition = 0;
int buttonState = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600); //Begin Serial
  lc.shutdown(0,false);  // Wake up displays
  lc.setIntensity(0,5);  // Set intensity levels
  lc.clearDisplay(0);  // Clear Displays
  sa44(); //Starting point
  pinMode(xPin, INPUT); //Declaring joystick
  pinMode(yPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
}
//  I then made a function to display each corresponsing point on the screen.
// For example, point (1,1) is a11, and the function is sa11.
// Point (2,3) is a23 and the function is sa23, etc.
// Again, I probably should have shortened it with for loops, but I don't know how to use them for multiple bytes.

void sa11() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a11[i]);
  }
}
void sa12() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a12[i]);
  }
}
void sa13() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a13[i]);
  }
}
void sa14() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a14[i]);
  }
}
void sa15() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a15[i]);
  }
}
void sa16() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a16[i]);
  }
}
void sa17() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a17[i]);
  }
}
void sa18() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a18[i]);
  }
}
void sa21() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a21[i]);
  }
}
void sa22() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a22[i]);
  }
}
void sa23() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a23[i]);
  }
}
void sa24() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a24[i]);
  }
}
void sa25() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a25[i]);
  }
}
void sa26() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a26[i]);
  }
}
void sa27() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a27[i]);
  }
}
void sa28() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a28[i]);
  }
}
void sa31() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a31[i]);
  }
}
void sa32() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a32[i]);
  }
}
void sa33() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a33[i]);
  }
}
void sa34() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a34[i]);
  }
}
void sa35() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a35[i]);
  }
}
void sa36() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a36[i]);
  }
}
void sa37() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a37[i]);
  }
}
void sa38() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a38[i]);
  }
}
void sa41() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a41[i]);
  }
}
void sa42() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a42[i]);
  }
}
void sa43() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a43[i]);
  }
}
void sa44() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a44[i]);
  }
}
void sa45() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a45[i]);
  }
}
void sa46() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a46[i]);
  }
}
void sa47() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a47[i]);
  }
}
void sa48() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a48[i]);
  }
}
void sa51() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a51[i]);
  }
}
void sa52() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a52[i]);
  }
}
void sa53() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a53[i]);
  }
}
void sa54() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a54[i]);
  }
}
void sa55() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a55[i]);
  }
}
void sa56() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a56[i]);
  }
}
void sa57() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a57[i]);
  }
}
void sa58() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a58[i]);
  }
}
void sa61() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a61[i]);
  }
}
void sa62() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a62[i]);
  }
}
void sa63() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a63[i]);
  }
}
void sa64() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a64[i]);
  }
}
void sa65() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a65[i]);
  }
}
void sa66() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a66[i]);
  }
}
void sa67() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a67[i]);
  }
}
void sa68() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a68[i]);
  }
}
void sa71() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a71[i]);
  }
}
void sa72() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a72[i]);
  }
}
void sa73() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a73[i]);
  }
}
void sa74() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a74[i]);
  }
}
void sa75() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a75[i]);
  }
}
void sa76() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a76[i]);
  }
}
void sa77() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a77[i]);
  }
}
void sa78() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a78[i]);
  }
}
void sa81() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a81[i]);
  }
}
void sa82() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a82[i]);
  }
}
void sa83() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a83[i]);
  }
}
void sa84() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a84[i]);
  }
}
void sa85() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a85[i]);
  }
}
void sa86() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a86[i]);
  }
}
void sa87() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a87[i]);
  }
}
void sa88() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,a88[i]);
  }
}
void snone() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,none[i]);
  }
}
void sall() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    lc.setRow(0,i,all[i]);
  }
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  xPosition = analogRead(xPin); //Read x, y, button values
  yPosition = analogRead(yPin);
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  Serial.print("\nX: "); //Print x, y, and button values to console
  Serial.print(xPosition);
  Serial.print(" \nY: ");
  Serial.print(yPosition);
  Serial.print(" \nButton: ");
  Serial.println(buttonState);
// This is the Logic behind it.
// The values range from 0 to 700: 340-350 being at rest, 0 being down, and 700 being up.
  if(xPosition < 250 && xPosition > 200) {
    sa43();
  }
  if(xPosition > 100 && xPosition < 200) {
    sa42();
  }
  if(xPosition == 0) {
    sa41();
  }
  if(xPosition > 400) {
    sa45();
  }
  if(yPosition == 0 && xPosition > 340 && xPosition < 350) {
    sa54();
  }
  if(yPosition > 600 && xPosition > 340 && xPosition < 350) {
    sa34();
  }
  if(xPosition > 340 && xPosition < 350 && yPosition > 340 && yPosition < 350) {
    sa44();
  }
  delay(10); //Wait 10 milliseconds before scanning for new input
  if(buttonState == 0) {
    //If button is pressed, light up whole screen.
    sall();
  }
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A *lot* of this code is indeed unnecessary. You can rewrite all those arrays and functions for the arrays to just 1 function :

```
void WriteBytes(byte* data, int length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        lc.setRow(0, i, data[i]);
}
```

Then you'd call it like this :

```
byte data[] =
{
   0x80,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
};
WriteBytes(data, sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Jamey D provided a nice answer. And Gernot1976 shows a good way of reducing your array declarations by dynamically generating the contents.

However, as your question refers to dealing with an actual array, I can show you how to do this using a reference to an array.

Using a template, you can easily pass in your arrays to a common function.
This method accepts a reference to an array. If you want to hard code the size `N` then you can remove the template altogether.

```
template< size_t N >
void WriteBytes( byte (&arr)[N] ){

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        lc.setRow(0, i, arr[i]);
    }
}

//Non template:
void WriteBytes( byte (&arr)[8] ){

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        lc.setRow(0, i, arr[i]);
    }
}
```

However your question asked for returning an array. So for sake of showing how, here is a small example. As I do not have `LedControl` & `lc` in these examples, its line is commented out.

```
//Use a typedef to make declarations simpler.
typedef byte (&ArrRef)[8]; //A reference to an array which contains 8 elements (type not variable)

ArrRef func(); //A prototype to prevent the IDE adding one above the typedef.

ArrRef func(){

  static byte arr[8];

  //Dynamically generate contents of array in arr.

  //Return the array
  return arr;
}

//The equivalent to the non-template version, just using a typedef instead.
void WriteBytes( ArrRef arr ); //Prototype.

void WriteBytes( ArrRef arr ){

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        //lc.setRow(0, i, arr[i]);
    }
}

void setup() {

  //Reference the array returned:
  ArrRef ref = func();

  //Use array
  for( byte el : ref ){

    //...
  }

  //Pass to function
  WriteBytes(ref);
}

void loop() {}
```

I have written a far more in depth [article here](http://arduino.land/FAQ/content/6/32/en/passing-arrays-to-functions.html), which covers the basics of passing arrays to functions using pointers and references to arrays.

Answer (score -2):

In C++ language arrays are pointers to memory blocks. So, you can return a pointer to array. Notice, that you can't return pointers to arrays created in function, because this memory can be (and possibly will be) overwritten.

```
byte a[100];
byte b[100];

byte* f(int x)
{
    if(x % 2 == 0)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}
```

Comment: An array is a legitimate type, which is not a 'pointer to a type', or a 'pointer type'. An array however will implicitly cast to a pointer, which points to its first element. An array reference or pointer can be returned safely if it is static, global, or passed into the function initially.